# MKOverlayRenderer to display UIImage over map view

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimage, mapkit

I'm trying to display an image over a map view in iOS 7.

I subclassed MKOverlayRenderer as follows:

MapOverlayRenderer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import MapKit;

@interface MapOverlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer

@end
```

MapOverlayRenderer.m

```
#import "MapOverlayRenderer.h"

@implementation MapOverlayRenderer

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];
    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
}

@end
```

And I have the following in my view controller which contains the map view:

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MapOverlayRenderer.h"
@import MapKit;

@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

    MapOverlayRenderer *mapOverlay = [[MapOverlayRenderer alloc] init];
    return mapOverlay;
}

- (IBAction)showSeattle:(id)sender {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = {47.61167908,-122.33325958};
    int radius = 100000; //radius in meters
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, radius, radius);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}

@end
```

When the `IBAction` is called to zoom the map to a location, I do not see the image on top of the map view.

How can you use the `MKOverlayRenderer` in iOS 7 to display images on top of a map view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. Where is the code actually adding an overlay to the map by calling `addOverlay`?  You'll need to create an object of type `id<MKOverlay>` and pass it in the `addOverlay` call.  You *could* create a custom class that implements `MKOverlay` but in this case, you could just use `MKCircle` to represent the position and size of your image.  In the `showSeattle:` method:

   ```
   CLLocationCoordinate2D location = {47.61167908,-122.33325958};
   int radius = 100000; //radius in meters

   MKCircle *c = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location radius:radius];
   [self.mapView addOverlay:c];

   MKCoordinateRegion region = ...
   ```
2. In `rendererForOverlay`, the code is creating an instance of `MapOverlayRenderer` but not giving it a reference to the underlying `overlay` model object.  Call `initWithOverlay` instead:

   ```
   MapOverlayRenderer *mapOverlay 
       = [[MapOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
   ```

By the way, you could put an image at the location much more easily using an annotation (but the image won't scale with the zoom level as an overlay-based image will).  Not sure which functionality you want.

Comment: Instead of using a circle overlay, can a polygon like a rectangle shape be used?

Comment: Yes, any overlay type that supplies what data MapOverlayRenderer needs is fine.  I used MKCircle because it was the easiest to create.

Comment: Also, please see my other question related to `MKOverlayRenderer` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558591/animated-gif-in-an-mkmapview-overlay-using-mkoverlayrenderer