# MKMapview: How to get moving directions of current location pin?

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, mapkit

I am working in a maps related application. In my application I would like to display destination pin and current location pin. On top of this I need to display an image like 'arrow' which should display moving direction of the user. Can anyone suggest me how do I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like an arrow pointing which way they are moving, so grab the heading, and draw an overlay image on the map of the arrow.  Then have it update the overlay when the heading changes.

documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008772

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1

also this might help: 
[MKOverlayRenderer to display UIImage over map view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459940/mkoverlayrenderer-to-display-uiimage-over-map-view)